# Rspec, Factory Girl build with has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have a model with one to many relationship, they are Poll and Choice.

How do I test them correctly, because below code causing `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:`. I want to create the parent (`Poll`) and its children (`Choices`) on the go, instead of create the parent (`Poll`) first then save the children (`Choices`) after that.

Here are the codes:

First, the error I got for all test cases:

```
Failure/Error: @poll = FactoryGirl.build(:poll_with_choices, user: @user)
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Choices choices required at least 2
```

**Poll model:**

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :choices
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :choices

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates_each :choices do |record, attr, value| 
    record.errors.add attr, "choices required at least 2" if record.choices.length < 2
  end
end
```

**Poll factory:**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :poll do
    title { FFaker::Lorem.phrase }
    description { FFaker::Lorem.sentences }
    user

    factory :poll_with_choices do  
      transient do 
        choices_count 3
      end

      after(:build) do |poll, evaluator|
        build_list(:choice, evaluator.choices_count)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Choice factory:**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :choice do
    label { FFaker::Name.name }
    votes 0
    poll
  end
end
```

**Poll spec**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Poll, type: :model do
  before do 
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @poll = FactoryGirl.build(:poll_with_choices, user: @user) 
  end

  subject { @poll }

  it { should respond_to(:title) }
  it { should respond_to(:description) }

  it { should validate_presence_of(:title) }

  it { should belong_to(:user) }
  it { should have_many(:choices) }
  it { should accept_nested_attributes_for(:choices) }

  describe "#save" do 
    before do 
      @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    end

    it "success" do 
      poll = FactoryGirl.build(:poll_with_choices, user: @user)
      expect(poll.save).to eql true
    end

    it "fail" do 
      poll = FactoryGirl.build(:poll, user: @user)
      poll.choices = FactoryGirl.build_list(:choice, 1)
      expect(poll.save).to eql false
    end
  end
end
```

As reference for `FactoryGirl.create`, **not** `FactoryGirl.build`: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Associations

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I get this working with FactoryGirl trait and `attributes`

Here is the `poll` factory code:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :poll do
    title { FFaker::Lorem.phrase }
    description { FFaker::Lorem.sentences }
    user
    choices_attributes { [FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:choice),     FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:choice), FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:choice)] }

    trait :with_many_choices do 
      choices_attributes { [
        FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:choice), FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:choice), 
        FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:choice), FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:choice), 
        FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:choice), FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:choice)
      ] }
    end

    trait :with_invalid_choices do 
      choices_attributes { [FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:choice),     FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:choice), FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:choice, label: '')] }
    end

    trait :with_lack_of_choices do 
      choices_attributes { [FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:choice)] }
    end

    trait :without_choices do 
      choices_attributes { [] }
    end
  end
end
```

References (Thanks to):

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html
- http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Traits
- https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/221

Answer (score 0):

If I see it correctly you have an error in your factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :poll do
    title { FFaker::Lorem.phrase }
    description { FFaker::Lorem.sentences }
    user

    factory :poll_with_choices do  
      transient do 
        choices_count 3
      end

      after(:build) do |poll, evaluator|
        build_list(:choice, evaluator.choices_count, poll: poll)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

you need to assign your poll to the choices otherwise the choice factory will create a poll for each choice.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem in your code. A poll object needs to exists so that choices may be added (you need the id to reference that in the choices) - but if you validate the existence of dependent objects (choices) before the parent object exists you are calling for problems and need to resort to strange code like you have. you should rethink the validation strategy.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in my case:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :store do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Store #{n}" }
    association :user
    sellers_attributes [ FactoryBot.attributes_for(:seller) ]
  end
end
```

I had to refactor my test and rename a few things.